# Como remover tags em um texto em Python?

Tags: html, python

Em PHP temos uma função chamada `strip_tags`que removem as tags HTML de um determinado texto.

Exemplo:

```
$text = "meu nome é <strong>Wallace</strong>";

strip_tags($text); // 'meu nome é Wallace'
```

Como eu posso fazer pra remover as tags de um texto em Python?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Um exemplo com [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) seria assim:

```
import re

text = 'meu nome é <strong>Wallace</strong>'
text = re.sub('<[^>]+?>', '', text)
print(text)
```

A função [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) recebe como primeiro parâmetro uma expressão regular e buscará no conteúdo, definido pelo terceiro parâmetro, trechos que combinam com a expressão, substituindo-os pelo conteúdo definido no segundo parâmetro.

Answer (score 11):

Existem várias maneiras, mas não creio que haja alguma melhor para cumprir este papel do que o [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> bs('<p>hey<span> brrh </span>lolol', 'html.parser').text
'hey brrh lolol'
```

> Nota: Para instalar no Python 3.5 use o `pip`:
>
> ```
> pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
> ```

[Leitura aprofundada](https://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://padabum.com/x.php%3Fid%3D211125&ved=0ahUKEwibgZyG5-3SAhVHxxQKHQC-CuEQFggZMAA&usg=AFQjCNF-qX_vxQfvSYF9jptqu6x-DsKLeA) acerca do BeautifulSoup

Comment: Bacana, funcionou no *Python 2.7* e *Python 3.**.  +1

Comment: Yap, é dos modulos que mais uso para o que faço @WallaceMaxters

Comment: Atualizei sua resposta para instruir quem não tiver o módulo instalado e deixei um +1 pra ti =)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento  Obrigado pelo acrescento na resposta, realmente é importante